# how to open usercontrol and close 2 seconds

Tags: c#, winforms

Hello People how can i open userControl and close in the 2 seconds and show another form?
c# WinForms

Comment: Are you asking how to create a splash screen that displays for two seconds before showing the program's main form?

Comment: It is a nonsense question, you cannot 'open a userControl'.  At best you can show a Form that contains that control.  A Timer could be next.

Comment: Jim is am doing that. Hans Ok it is not problem i can show form

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
public void MyFunction()
{
    firstForm.ShowDialog();
    secondForm.Show();
}

public void firstForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Timer timer = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer() { Interval = 2000 };
    timer.Tick += delegate { timer.Stop(); Close(); };
    timer.Start();
}
```